# is $T/N$ the same as $T$ intersection $N^c$

Tags: probability

is $T/N$ the same as $T$ intersection $N^c$ ? I got the answer $T/N$ for the question "News is obtained from television but *not* newspapers, but the answer key says that the answer is $T$ intersection $N$ complement.  Are these two the same?

Comment: I would write $T \setminus N$ and not $T/N$ for this.  And think of the symbol `\setminus` as a sort of minus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, we have $$T\setminus N = \{ x\in T \mid x\notin N \}$$
and
$$T\cap N^c = \{ x\mid x\in T \} \cap \{ x\mid x\in N^c \}=\{ x\in T \mid x\in N^c \}.$$

Since $x\in N^c$ if and only if $x\notin N$, you are right: $T\setminus N = T\cap N^c$.

*PS:* the correct $\LaTeX$ command is `\setminus`.